# JavaScript Animation on text

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I would like to animate a text during loading and repeat this animation as long as my AJAX request is not finished.
But my animation is not repeat when it's finished.
Someone could explain me why this animation don't get repeated please
I tried to put a setTimeout function but it doesn't work well.
I also tried an infinite loop but it not succeed

```js
document.getElementById("generateButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var loadingIndicator = document.getElementById("loadingIndicator");
  loadingIndicator.style.display = "block";

  var chars = document.querySelectorAll(".char");
  var delay = 0;

  function repeatAnimation() {
    chars.forEach(function(char) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        char.style.animationName = "bounce";
      }, delay);
      delay += 100; // Ajustez ce délai pour contrôler la séquence
    });

    setTimeout(repeatAnimation, 1000); // Lancer la prochaine répétition
  }

  var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("description").value;
  var titleValue = document.getElementById("title").value;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/generationDescription", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      loadingIndicator.style.display = "none";

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("description").value = response.description;
        document.getElementById("shortDescription").value =
          response.shortDescription;
      }
    }
  };

  var data =
    "description=" +
    encodeURIComponent(descriptionValue) +
    "&title=" +
    encodeURIComponent(titleValue);
  repeatAnimation();
  xhr.send(data);
});
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}

.loading-indicator .char {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loadingIndicator" class="loading-indicator" style="display: none;">
  <span class="char">C</span>
  <span class="char">h</span>
  <span class="char">a</span>
  <span class="char">r</span>
  <span class="char">g</span>
  <span class="char">e</span>
  <span class="char">m</span>
  <span class="char">e</span>
  <span class="char">n</span>
  <span class="char">t</span>
  <span class="char"> </span>
  <!-- Espace entre les mots -->
  <span class="char">e</span>
  <span class="char">n</span>
  <span class="char"> </span>
  <!-- Espace entre les mots -->
  <span class="char">c</span>
  <span class="char">o</span>
  <span class="char">u</span>
  <span class="char">r</span>
  <span class="char">s</span>
  <span class="char">.</span>
  <span class="char">.</span>
  <span class="char">.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that the animation doesn't repeat after the `AJAX` request finishes. This happens because you initiate the animation before sending the `AJAX` request, and there's no way to halt or restart the animation once the request is finished. Using `setTimeout` to repeat the animation doesn't allow you to stop it effectively.

Try this code;

```
document.getElementById("generateButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var loadingIndicator = document.getElementById("loadingIndicator");
  loadingIndicator.style.display = "block";

  var chars = document.querySelectorAll(".char");
  var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("description").value;
  var titleValue = document.getElementById("title").value;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/generationDescription", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      loadingIndicator.style.display = "none";

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("description").value = response.description;
        document.getElementById("shortDescription").value = response.shortDescription;
      }
    }
  };

  var data =
    "description=" + encodeURIComponent(descriptionValue) +
    "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(titleValue);

  xhr.send(data);

  // Start the animation loop after making the AJAX request
  var animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
    chars.forEach(function (char) {
      char.style.animationName = "bounce";
    });
  }, 1000);

  // Stop the animation loop when the AJAX request is complete
  xhr.onload = function () {
    clearInterval(animationInterval);
  };
});
```